# How to insert a line break in itext7 table cell

Tags: c#, itext7

How can I insert a line break in itext7 table cell?
here is my code,

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\Temp\test123.pdf");
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.LEGAL);
string msg = $"This is line 1{Environment.NewLine}This should be line 2, However it's not showing";
Table table = new Table(1, true);
Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(msg));
table.AddCell(cell);
document.Add(table);
document.Close();
Process.Start(@"C:\Temp\test123.pdf");
```

Comment: Try instead inserting multiple `Paragraph`

Comment: You should make that an answer @zcui93 because that's indeed the solution.

Comment: You should make that an answer @zcui93 because that's indeed the solution

Comment: Genuine iText developer appears :) @BrunoLowagie

Comment: Yes, and I appreciate your answer. I gave it an up-vote.

Answer (score 8):

You should generally use `Paragraph` instead of *manually* setting line breaks when using PDF generation tools like `iText`.

```
var cell = new Cell();
cell.Add(new Paragraph("This is line 1");
cell.Add(new Paragraph("This should be line 2, and it is!~");
```

Answer (score 0):

As of at least v7 itext now supports using new lines for line breaks:

```cs
var table = new Table( 1 );

var p = new Paragraph()
    .Add( "Line 1" )
    .Add( Environment.NewLine ) // or just "\r\n"
    .Add( "Line 2" );

table.AddCell( p );
```